# Is there a quick way to find the smallest $n$ such that $a^2+b^2\mid n^2$?

Tags: number-theory

Right now I factorize $a^2+b^2$ into primes and look for odd prime powers. Not very quick though for large numbers. I'm wondering if there is some number theory magic for this.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the context? I would say the smallest such $n$ is $0$ as $a=b=0$ all works. Or if $n$ need be positive, $a=0$, $b=1$ and $n=1$ works as well. Then the next is $n=2$ with $b=2$, $a=0$ or $n=5$, with $a=3$, $b=4$.

Comment: No, $a$ and $b$ are given.

Comment: If you know the smallest $n$, then you get information about $a^2+b^2$, for example, you can tell whether it is squarefree. Telling whether a number is squarefree is held to be as hard as factoring, which is believed to be hard. The bottom line is, I think there is no faster way than what you already do.